# accessing struct variable inside getter setter in a c++ class

Tags: c++, struct, setter, getter

Okay, I have something like this in C++:

```
class MyClass{
private:
  int someVariable;
  int someOtherVariable;

  struct structName{
    int someStructVariable;
    int someOtherStructVariable;
  };//end of struct

public:
  //getters & setters for the defined variables.

  int getSomeStructVariable()
  {
    // this does not work I get this error: "error: expected primary-expression
    // before '.' token"
    return structName.someStructVariable;
  } 
};//end of class
```

How should I write my getter or setter in this case?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`structName` is part of the type name, not the variable name.  You need to give it a name, something like:

```
struct structName {
  int someStructVariable;
  int someOtherStructVariable;
} myStructure;
```

And then in your accessor use:

```
return myStructure.someStructVariable;
```

That should get you the result you want.  Other alternatives for the structure variable are to separate out the structure definition from the variable declaration:

```
struct structName {
  int someStructVariable;
  int someOtherStructVariable;
};

struct structName myStructure;
```

or to add in `typedef`:

```
typedef struct structName {
  int someStructVariable;
  int someOtherStructVariable;
} structTypedefName;

structTypedefName myStructure;
```

Comment: No need for typedef to drop the struct class-key, `struct Name {}; Name variable;` works fine.

Comment: O RLY?  I'm not a C++ guy, I'm afraid.  C definitely requires the `typedef`.  I guess it makes sense; C++ doesn't require the `class` keyword to be around when you declare instances either.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct A {
  A() : _n(0) {}
  int get_n() const {
    return _n;
  }
  void calculate(int a) {
    _n = a * a * a;
  }
private:
  int _n;
};
```

Here's a complete example. If you want a mirror `set_n` instead of something which manipulates the data, then you should probably drop the getter/setter (as you'd be using them incorrectly) and make the data member public.

Also, remember: defining classes with `struct` works *identically* to defining classes with `class` but for one exception: public instead of private as the default access for members and bases.

Comment: Now that someone has kindly edited the code, I see I've misread the problem.  (D'oh.)  Going to leave the answer up anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to write a getter/setter for each structure field. A better solution is:

```
typedef struct {
    int field1;
    int field2;
} structType;

class MyClass {
private:
    structType _structName;
public:
    const structType & getStructName() const {
        return _structName;
    }
}
```

Keep `structType` and `MyClass` separate. Use the getter as:

```
MyClass m;
int var;
var = m.getStructName().field1;
```

The first `const` is needed to return a const value. The second one is needed for [const-correctness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8277801/what-is-the-definition-of-const-correctness).

There are two ways to define a setter:

```
class MyClass {
// ...
public:
    // type 1
    void setStructName(const structType &s) {
        _structName = s;
    }
    // type 2
    structType & setStructName() {
        return _structName;
    }
}
```

Use the first one as:

```
MyClass m;
structType s;
m.setStructName(s);
```

The second version enables you to modify separate structure fields as well:

```
m.setStructName() = s;
m.setStructName().field1 = 10;
```

Note that the setter might need some adjustments if the structure contains pointers.